# Dynamical output in Python Functions

Tags: python, function, output

When we use def, we can use **kwargs and *args to define dynamic inputs to the function

Is there anything similar for the return tuples, I've been looking for something that behaves like this:

```
def foo(data):
    return 2,1

a,b=foo(5)
a=2
b=1
a=foo(5)
a=2
```

However if I only declare one value to unpack, it sends the whole tuple over there:

```
a=foo(5)
a=(2,1)
```

I could use 'if' statements, but I was wondering if there was something less cumbersome. I could also use some hold variable to store that value, but my return value might be kind of large to have just some place holder for that.

Thanks

Comment: If you want `a` to always contain the first value, then you can do `a = foo(5)[0]`. Is that what you were asking for, or do you need a more general solution?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen to your multiple result values?

Comment: Marius, I think that is what I was looking for, just felt a bit hacky, and was wondering if there was a more sophisticated way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to fully generalize the return value, you could do something like this:

```
def function_that_could_return_anything(data): 
    # do stuff
    return_args = ['list', 'of', 'return', 'values']
    return_kwargs = {'dict': 0, 'of': 1, 'return': 2, 'values': 3}
    return return_args, return_kwargs

a, b = function_that_could_return_anything(...)
for thing in  a: 
    # do stuff

for item in b.items(): 
    # do stuff
```

In my opinion it would be simpler to just return a dictionary, then access parameters with `get()`:

```
dict_return_value = foo()
a = dict_return_value.get('key containing a', None)
if a:
    # do stuff with a
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite understand exactly what you're asking, so I'll take a couple guesses.

---

If you want to use a single value sometimes, consider a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

AAndB = namedtuple('AAndB', 'a b')

def foo(data):
    return AAndB(2,1)

# Unpacking all items.
a,b=foo(5)

# Using a single value.
foo(5).a
```

---

Or, if you're using Python 3.x, there's [extended iterable unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to easily unpack only some of the values:

```
def foo(data):
    return 3,2,1

a, *remainder = foo(5) # a==3, remainder==[2,1]
a, *remainder, c = foo(5) # a==3, remainder==[2], c==1
a, b, c, *remainder = foo(5) # a==3, b==2, c==1, remainder==[]
```

Sometimes the name `_` is used to indicate that you are discarding the value:

```
a, *_ = foo(5)
```